# How to determine if a GeoTIFF image is a photo or a raster map using GDAL and Python

Tags: python, gdal

Does anyone have a method to determine if a GeoTIFF image is a photo (e.g aerial ortho) vs a raster map (e.g topographic map produced from vectors) using GDAL and Python? Both images are RGB/RGBA uncompressed with a byte datatype.

Comment: Read the metadata? Perhaps look at histograms or check compressed size v uncompressed (maps with only a few colours and larger contiguous areas of the same colour compress much better than aerial/sat images) and derive an empirical measure.

Comment: How many bands do each have? Are you looking for a way to differentiate any aerial imagery (i.e. including singleband orthos) from topos?

Comment: Count the number of distinct colors. Maps should have much less of them. Unfortunately I don't know what method to use.

Comment: Some images have 3 bands, other 4bands (RGBA RGBA)

Comment: The metadata doesn't give any data in my example unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see from the raster histograms that orthoimagery has a much different frequency distribution than [topos](https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/topoview/viewer/#13/47.8299/-90.0195).

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show_hist

ortho = '/path/to/ortho/q1456nw.tif'
raster = rasterio.open(ortho)
show_hist(raster, bins=50, lw=0.0, stacked=False, alpha=0.3, histtype='stepfilled', title="Geotiff Ortho Histogram")

topo = '/path/to/topo/MN_Marr_Island_20190605_TM_geo.tif'
raster2 = rasterio.open(topo)
show_hist(raster2, bins=50, lw=0.0, stacked=False, alpha=0.3, histtype='stepfilled', title="Geotiff Topo Histogram")
```

[image]

Differentiating the images can be done using simple descriptive statistics such as median or a count of unique values. For example, here are the median values for band 1 in each image:

```
# Stats
img = raster.read(1) # Ortho
numpy.median(img)

img2 = raster2.read(1) # Topo
numpy.median(img2)
```

---

```
In [4]: img = raster.read(1)
   ...: numpy.median(img)
Out[4]: 114.0

In [5]: img2 = raster2.read(1)
   ...: numpy.median(img2)
Out[5]: 255.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is wonderful.

This worked for me something like:

<pre>
median('../_garbage/topo.tif')
Band 1: Mean = 213.6
Band 2: Mean = 212.51
Band 3: Mean = 202.2
Band 4: Mean = 255.0
>>> median('../imagery.tif')
Band 1: Mean = 74.67
Band 2: Mean = 92.07
Band 3: Mean = 69.8
Band 4: Mean = 255.0
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Aaron's help I landed on this as a solution that worked for me:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

def is_map(file_path):
    tile = gdal.Open(file_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    band1 = tile.GetRasterBand(1)
    return np.median(np.array(band1.ReadAsArray())) > 100.0
```